# Issue system call from Python, get filename for output

Tags: python, c, pipe

I am writing a Python program that calls a library ([GenomeTools](http://genometools.org/)) via its C API. There is a function in GenomeTools that takes a filename as input and processes the file's contents in a single pass.

I am wondering if there is a way I can issue a system call from Python and have that C function process the output of the system call. I typically use the `subprocess` module when I want to issue system calls in Python, but this is different since the C function takes a filename as input. Is there a way I can assign a filename to the output of the system call?

Comment: You are saying that the system call outputs the filename needed by the C function? In that case, just capture stdout and parse it.

Comment: No, the system call outputs data. I want to call a function that processes that data, but that function only accepts a filename as input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe the system call output to a temporary file and then use its filename for your C call. Wit hany luck, you delete the file before it even gets out of the RAM cache onto the disk.

```
import tempfile
import subprocess as subp
import os

tempfp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
try:
    proc = subp.Popen(['somecommand'], stdout=tempfp)
    tempfp.close()
    proc.wait()
    some_c_function(tempfp.name)
finally:
    tempfp.close()
    os.remove(tempfp.name)
```

Comment: Does `tempfp.close()` need to be in the *try* block since it is in the *finally* block?

Comment: The `proc.wait()` command allows the system command to complete before proceeding. I'm assuming this is to avoid issues that would arise if the Python/C program was trying to read data faster than the system call could write it?

Comment: @DanielStandage -yes, it makes sure the that file has been completely written and flushed to the file system. Otherwise, the C function would see end-of-file well before the full data is written. Its very uncommon, but if the C function keeps checking the file, you could call it first and close later to get greater parallelism.

Comment: @DanielStandage - good point. The parent should close it as soon as possible after starting the child so that you don't have any open file descriptor problems (a potential broken link exception). I'm moving it before the wait. Its in the finally block just in case the Popen call itself fails.